# How to combine two 3x3 rotation matrices to align accelerometer axes with another coordinate system

Tags: linear-algebra, accelerometer, matrix-multiplication, quaternions, rotational-matrices

I am trying to align the X, Y, Z axes from an accelerometer to the X, Y, Z axes of a vehicle.

My approach consists of two steps:

**1 step:** Find a rotation matrix Rz to align the Z axes of both coordinate systems. I know the acceleration vector of the vehicle is `A_veh=(0,0,1000)` (values in mg) when is stopped on a level surface, so I measure the acceleration reported by the accelerometer at that very moment and I get my vector `A_acc=(6,64,1016)` (values in mg), so I proceed to find a rotation matrix to align A_acc with the Z-axis of the vehicle (A_veh). I form the ration matrix by using the implementation of the Rodriguez formula listed [here](http://www.j3d.org/matrix_faq/matrfaq_latest.html#Q38) and we find out:

```
`Rz[][] = 0.999983    -0.000185    -0.005894
         -0.000185     0.998022    -0.062866
          0.005894     0.062866     0.998005`
```

To verify the rotation matrix I multiply the A_acc vector by Rz and get an aligned vector `A_z_aligned=(0.000000,0.000000,1018)` (in mg) which is the expected since all the acceleration is on the Z-axis of the vehicle.

[Image showing debug info about the process of getting Rz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqoQl.png)

**2 step:** Find a rotation matrix Rxy to align the XY axes of both coordinate systems. Measuring some acceleration of the vehicle with an external sensor, I get the following acceleration vector for the vehicle `A_veh=(-323,0,1009)` and from the accelerometer, I get `A_acc=(-11,-322,1009)` (in mg), so repeating the procedure from step 1 I get the rotation matrix Rxy:

```
`Rxy[][] =  0.954307     0.135202    -0.266494
           -0.050168     0.951624     0.303143
            0.294151    -0.275922     0.914924`
```

And to verify this rotation matrix I multiply the A_acc vector by Rxy and get an aligned vector `A_xy_aligned=(-322,0,1008)` which is the expected.

[Image showing debug info about the process of getting Rxy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubuV5.png)

**Question:** How can I "combine" the two rotation matrices in order to have **one** rotation matrix that allows me to align any raw acceleration vector read from the accelerometer to the vehicle axes?

I have tried multiplying the raw acceleration vectors by Rz and then by Rxy and it seems it does not work.

I also tried multiplying both matrices Rz*Rxy=R and use R to align the raw vectors but it does not work either.

I need some help with this topic.

Thanks,

Comment: did you ever find out how to resolve this? Can you answer this question with the solution you came up with?